# Running the same cypress tests on multiple domains

Tags: cypress

We manage a long list of similar sites operating in multiple markets, a lot of these are config driven and sometimes releases can break things on only some of the domains.

So I would like to build out a list of tests driven by config to check all our domains are fine before a release.

See the basic example below which works fine if we change it to [beforeEach] but if we use [before] then after the first set of tests cypress just keeps reloading and eventually navigates to the domain.

All works fine when we use beforeEach but obviously, this is much slower when we doing noninteractive checks like just checking the content of the page.

Please advise what the recommended way of looping over multiple domains to execute the same tests.

```
config.sites.forEach((site) => {
        describe('Testing SEO:' + site.url, function() {
            before(function() {
                cy.visit(site.url); 
            });

            it('Check there is only one h1 on the page on', function() {
                cy.get('h1').should('have.length', 1)
            });

            it('Checks the contents of an h1', function() {
                cy.get('h1').should('have.text', site.seo.h1)
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: No worries ignore my question above i had to use `beforeEach` instead of `before` and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you're correct that it's slower to `cy.visit` on each test, this is actually the way that Cypress recommends to write your tests.

According to the ["Best Practices" documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Creating-%E2%80%9Ctiny%E2%80%9D-tests-with-a-single-assertion), you shouldn't create a bunch of tests that only test a single assertion.

Cypress will tell you which assertion failed anyways, so splitting your assertions into multiple `it`s will not provide you any benefit.

I would recommend doing it like this:

```js
config.sites.forEach((site) => {
        describe('Testing SEO:' + site.url, function() {
            beforeEach(function() {
                cy.visit(site.url); 
            });

            it('Check all headers', function() {
                cy.get('h1').should('have.length', 1)
                cy.get('h1').should('have.text', site.seo.h1)
            });
        });
});
```